# Print __file__ without file extension

Tags: python

Is there a better way to print `__file__` without the extension?

```
import os
print os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]
```

Comment: what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: I was hoping to find a way where I didn't have to import os.  Maybe with split?

Comment: `os` is actually imported anyway, you're not doing any harm importing it again.

Comment: Bingo - print __file__.split('.')[0]

Comment: @Ethan won't work for a file named `my.cool.script.py`

Comment: @Ethan Whitt, you can't use use split naively as there could be dots in other parts of the file path. eg `myfile.2.txt`

Comment: @Ethan Whitt: no that' wrong: `os.path.splitext("something.stupid.txt")[0]` vs. `"something.stupid.txt".split('.')[0]`

Comment: I think the OP's original question is okay; it's just that the answer is "NO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `split()`, without `os`: `file[:file.find('.')]`.

(inb4 a captain obvious jumps in with a comment: with the assumption that you have **one** '.' in `file`).

Comment: see comments to the question. Does not work with any filename.

Comment: I don't see that stated as a requirement anywhere.

Comment: If you decide to use this approach, use `rfind` so it searches from the *end* of the string: `file[:file.rfind('.')]`

Comment: @zeekay Thats even better than my approach with reversing the string. Genius ! :P

Answer (score 12):

You can use `string.split`,  but what's the point? The standard library is giving you the exact tool you need.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer.  The OP wants the filename without an extension.  The `os` module is part of the **STANDARD** library. The `splitext` does exactly what the OP wants to do.  Exactly!! Avoiding the obvious, proper solution in order to avoid typing `import os` is not good practice! (A fancy solution with `split` belongs in code golf, not serious programming.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this, use `os.path.splitext`. *However* if you *must*, here's a way:

```
'.'.join(__file__.split('.')[:-1])
```

Comment: Like the "if you must" and the `[:-1]` alternative to `rsplit`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'my.cool.script.py'.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
<<< 'my.cool.script'
```